# Will I have to purchase a cross-play game twice?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps-vita

I'm pretty excited about the the idea of continuing my PS3 save game on the go with the PS Vita. This is one of the deciding features for me when it comes to whether or not I will invest in one of these nifty little devices. My only worry is that I will have to buy the game twice; both on PS3 and PS Vita.

So does anyone know if this will be the case? I've heard that it is a single buy and that supporting games come with a PSN download code for the alternate version but I have never seen any concrete evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Eurogamer has just put up [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-02-16-sony-details-one-price-vita-ps3-cross-play-content) that quotes Sony as saying

> "Those who already own any of these titles for their PS3 systems will be able to download this same content to their PS Vita systems for free, and vice versa," Sony said. "There is no need to pay for the same content twice, highlighting the importance of the relationship between PS3 and PS Vita."

However, the feature does not currently extend to *all* PS3 games - at least, not out of the box.

From [this IGN article](http://uk.psp.ign.com/articles/121/1213821p1.html):

> "The rumor suggested that a firmware update would add the feature to all past and future PlayStation 3 games, but Sony has now confirmed that this won't be the case...The compatibility is achieved on the side of the PS3 game, just like normal."

So the streaming functionality has to be written into the PS3 game for it to work, and that is up to each developer.

There is an alternative, though. There are some [custom tools](http://www.mod-gadget.com/ps-vita-play-ps3-games-custom-firmware-remote-play/) that allow any game to be streamed, albeit not without some lag problems or occasional instability.

Comment: Yeah thats kind of what I thought, thanks for the extra information too :)